# Absolute paths of files in iOS applications in swift

Tags: ios, swift, file, directory

I need to be able to reference a file which is stored in my Xcode project in the following way:

[image: thing]

I want to be able to use files which I have stored inside of the "data" folder.

How do I reference it to be able to read its contents? What is it's directory path?

Comment: I think you should read the official Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html) about file management.

Comment: I have read those and I understand them, but my problem is that it doesn't genuinely help me with my problem. It won't tell me how to reference the "data" folder in the example above. Something which I believe must be very trivial. Do you know the answer?

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it out. The apple swift documentation and other developer references are really unclear about it.

The way you would reference the "data" folder so as to scan the entire contents is by writing the following:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath?.stringByAppendingPathComponent("data")

var error: NSError?

let filesInDirectory: [String]! = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(path!, error: &error) as? [String]
```

This will return the contents of the files in the "data" folder as an array of filenames.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Relative to swift 3

```
let bundleURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL
let dataFolderURL = bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("data")
let fileURL = dataFolderURL.appendingPathComponent("file.txt")
print(fileURL.path)
print(FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let bundleURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL
let dataFolderURL = bundleURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("data")
let fileURL = dataFolderURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("fileName.txt")
```